# Group and count array by date in javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays, sorting

I'm having a problem grouping this data using javascript. Just starting my career using pure javascript and nodeJS for building a website application.

here's my data result using typeORM.

```
let data = [
            {
              control_no: '01-55-10-021-000001',
              date_created: '2023-01-05',
              validated: '1',
              date_validated: '2023-01-06',
              submitted: '1',
              date_submitted: '2023-01-07'
            },
            {
              control_no: '01-55-10-016-000190',
              date_created: '2023-01-05',
              validated: '1',
              date_validated: '2023-01-06',
              submitted: '0',
              date_submitted: null
            },
            {
              control_no: '01-55-10-001-000001',
              date_created: '2023-01-06',
              validated: '0',
              date_validated: null,
              submitted: '0',
              date_submitted: null
            },
            {
              control_no: '01-55-10-001-000002',
              date_created: '2023-01-06',
              validated: '0',
              date_validated: null,
              submitted: '0',
              date_submitted: null
            },
            {
              control_no: '01-55-10-001-000003',
              date_created: '2023-01-06',
              validated: '0',
              date_validated: null,
              submitted: '0',
              date_submitted: null
            },
            {
              control_no: '01-55-10-001-000004',
              date_created: '2023-01-06',
              validated: '1',
              date_validated: '2023-01-07',
              submitted: '1',
              date_submitted: '2023-01-08'
            },
            {
              control_no: '01-55-10-001-000005',
              date_created: '2023-01-06',
              validated: '1',
              date_validated: '2023-01-07',
              submitted: '0',
              date_submitted: null
            },
            {
              control_no: '01-55-10-001-000006',
              date_created: '2023-01-06',
              validated: '1',
              date_validated: '2023-01-07',
              submitted: '1',
              date_submitted: '2023-01-08'
            },
            {
              control_no: '01-55-10-001-000007',
              date_created: '2023-01-09',
              validated: '0',
              date_validated: null,
              submitted: '0',
              date_submitted: null
            },
            {
              control_no: '01-55-10-001-000008',
              date_created: '2023-01-09',
              validated: '0',
              date_validated: null,
              submitted: '0',
              date_submitted: null
            }
          ];
```

now i want to have this structure of data where i want to count all data as **created** then count all validated data as **validated** and all tagged as submitted as **submitted** by date

```
let created = [
                {
                    date: '2023-01-05',
                    count: 2
                },
                {
                    date: '2023-01-06',
                    count: 6
                },
                {
                    date: '2023-01-09',
                    count: 2
                }
            ];

            let validated = [
                {
                    date: '2023-01-06',
                    count: 2
                },
                {
                    date: '2023-01-07',
                    count: 3
                }
            ]

            let submitted = [
                {
                    date: '2023-01-07',
                    count: 1
                },
                {
                    date: '2023-01-08',
                    count: 2
                }
            ]
```

then sort by date.

i'm not that good in manipulating arrays using javascript, been in PHP in so many years.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this by using 1 reduce.But I am using 3 different reduce function

1. For Created:

```js
let created = data.reduce((acc, curr) => {
  let key = curr.date_created;
  if (!acc[key]) {
    acc[key] = {
      date: key,
      count: 1
    };
  } else {
    acc[key].count++;
  }
  return acc;
}, {});

// convert the object to array
created = Object.values(created); 

//  sort data by date
created.sort((a,b) => new Date(a.date) - new Date(b.date)); 

console.log(created)
```

2. for validated

```js
let validated = data.reduce((acc, curr) => {
  let key = curr.date_validated;
  if (!acc[key]) {
    acc[key] = {
      date: key,
      count: 1
    };
  } else {
    acc[key].count++;
  }
  return acc;
}, {});

// convert the object to array
validated = Object.values(validated); 

// remove the null value
validated = validated.filter(val => val.date != null) 

// sort the data by date
validated.sort((a,b) => new Date(a.date) - new Date(b.date));
```

3.For submitted

```js
let submitted = data.reduce((acc, curr) => {
  let key = curr.date_submitted;
  if (!acc[key]) {
    acc[key] = {
      date: key,
      count: 1
    };
  } else {
    acc[key].count++;
  }
  return acc;
}, {});

// convert the object to array
submitted = Object.values(submitted); 

// remove the null values
submitted = submitted.filter(val => val.date != null) 

//sort the data by date
submitted.sort((a, b) => new Date(a.date) - new Date(b.date));
```

If you still face any issue. Please let me know